# Dynamically add, hide or forget Tkinter Frames based on Dictionary Record values?

Tags: python, user-interface, dictionary, tkinter, event-handling

I am building a GUI application to monitor/control remote embedded client devices.  Each client's state machine is maintained in a master dictionary and is to be represented in the GUI as an instance of a tab (Frame) in a Notebook widget.  I want to instantiate a tab (defined as a class in my application) whenever a new client registers and hide or forget the tab when the client link times out.  I'll re-instantiate if/when the client re-registers.

I'm new to Python, Tkinter and OO in general and am struggling with program structure.  I need to continuously loop through the dictionary records to refresh the GUI, but I've concluded I can't iterate within the root.mainloop() structure.  So "external" changes in state machine dictionary records or elements need to refresh corresponding GUI Notebook tab instances externally, including creating and removing instances of my tab class.

I'm confident there is a standard practice but I haven't progressed sufficiently in my learning to figure this out.  Some quick suggestions to nudge me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You are correct that one should not loop continuously (or very long) within an event handler.  The substitute for tkinter is to use the .after function.  There are several examples in answers here on SO, including some of mine.

Comment: Found .after, including one of your examples.  It seems like the solution I need to refresh within my GUI object... just need to shift my paradigm to do dictionary management within the object, not externally as I was trying to do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to address three elements to get my solution working:

1)  Use the root.after function to enable external asynchronous events (eg. non-tkinter GUI events) to control GUI elements using an update method... Thank-you Terry Jan Reedy!

2)  Perform overall dictionary updates WITHIN the GUI instantiation itself as a method instead of trying to handle my dictionary management using a separate function.  Perhaps this is obvious to most but it was a paradigm shift for me.

3)  The GUI needs to be a single instantiation of my class for all dictionary elements, not an individual instantiation for each element.

Code snip below.

```
def remote_window_mgr():
    remote_window = client_gui()


class client_gui(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title('Client Manager')

        # Create main Frame in Window
        main_frame = ttk.Frame(self.root, borderwidth = 5, relief = 'ridge')
        main_frame.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = (N, W, E, S))
        main_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        main_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        # Create Notebook widget to host Client Tabs
        self.tab_frame = ttk.Notebook(main_frame)
        self.tab_frame.grid(column = 1, row = 1)

        self.root.after(1000, func=self.gui_update)
        self.root.mainloop()


    def gui_update(self):

        for client_id in list(Client_Records.keys()):
            # Check for new Client
            if client_id not in list(Client_Tabs.keys()):
                client_data = Client_Records[client_id]
                # Create Client Tab
                self.add_tab(client_id)

        for client_id in list(Client_Tabs.keys()):
            # Check if Client Record has been purged...
            if client_id not in list(Client_Records.keys()):
                # Client Record no longer exists, delete Client Tab
                self.remove_tab(client_id)
                del Client_Tabs[client_id]

        for client_id in list(Client_Tabs.keys()):
            # Refresh client tabs for all active clients
            self.update_tab(client_id)

        self.root.after(1000, func=self.gui_update)
```

Comment: It's nice to see someone run with a hint and solve his problem.  Event-loop programming can seem update-down from the perspective of traditional imperative programming with top-down control.  The Twisted package is named as it is to reflect that.  If you were doing other things with the gui and found that gui_update locked up the gui too long, you could split into `update_new`, `update_old`, and `update_all`, and have each set up the next in round-robin fashion, with delays that total about 1000 - execution time.   IE, `update_new` could end with `root.after(0, update_old)`.

Comment: Great insights... thank-you.  My last direct experience with programming was with MC6800 Assembly and C... embedded and top down.  Just now getting up to speed on OO, Sockets and GUI's.  ;-)  Appreciate your help.